# Download part of a file

Tags: php

How I can download a file, for example - from 3MB to 10MB (so I want skip 3MB and continue download from this byte). Is it possible? How I can do it without waste the time.

Thanks.

Comment: Send a byte `Range:` header along, if the serving party supports partial HTTP downloads.

Comment: Can u give me example?